# Algorithm for very simple voice/speech recognition

Tags: android, algorithm, speech-recognition, google-glass, voice-recognition

I'm writing a game for Google Glass, but unfortunately SpeechRecognizer API isn't available on the current builds on Google Glass GDK.

So I've been thinking about implementing an algorithm for a very simple voice recognition.
Let's say I want to recognize only: "Yes" and "No".
Do you know any example code or any helpful resources to help me in implementing this ?
Is it so hard that I should drop the idea and go with big frameworks like CMUSphinx ?

What about recognizing: up, down, right, left or numbers from 1 to 10 ?

Comment: Usually, you train your voice recognition using Hidden Markov Models (HMM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I know, there often used transition to the frequency domain by [fast Fourier transform (FFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and it analyzing. Also need some dictionary of speeched words for frequency correlation.

Please see this links:

[CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) have java implementation.

[David Wagner](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj/speech.html) have a good article and matlab implementation.

P.S. Ohh, if you speak in russian, why you don't read [this](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135087/) article - very simple, with java examples.

P.P.S. Honestly, I never use this framework, but if you have only a superficial knowledge about speech recognition, robust and easyest way is to use existing complete solutions like frameworks or libraries, otherwise you need spend time to possess the necessary knowledge threshold. In this case you can read [this](http://revistaie.ase.ro/content/46/s%20-%20furtuna.pdf) article.

Comment: Looks like PocketSphinx (part of CMU Sphinx) is the way to go.